# AVPlayer in fullscreen doesn't rotate

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

In our project we have blocked/unblocked the orientations of a view following this [post](http://www.jairobjunior.com/blog/2016/03/05/how-to-rotate-only-one-view-controller-to-landscape-in-ios-slash-swift/) and inserting the code below. Everything works great.

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(window?.rootViewController) {
        if (rootViewController.respondsToSelector(Selector("canRotate"))) {
            // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
            return .AllButUpsideDown;
        }
    }

    // Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
    return .Portrait;
}

private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    if (rootViewController == nil) { return nil }
    if (rootViewController.isKindOfClass(UITabBarController)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController((rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.isKindOfClass(UINavigationController)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController((rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
...
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated : Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (self.isMovingFromParentViewController()) {
            UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }

    func canRotate() -> Void {}
}
```

The app is portrait-only, except a view where we have enable all the orientations. In this view there are also a container with an AVPlayer and the problem is that I don't know how to enable all orientations in this AVPlayerViewController also. The app allows all orientations in the view that contains the player, but once I have put the player in fullscreen this one doesn't rotate.  I have tried using the code previously mentioned in the AVPlayerViewController of the AVPlayer in the container, but the player doesn't rotate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=avplayerviewcontroller+rotate

Comment: @matt we have tried dozens posts but nothing works

Comment: But what does that tell you? It tells you that asking the same question _again_ will add nothing to the mix.